# What drawbacks are there in scheduling an event to run every too often,say after every 60 seconds?

Tags: mysql

I have this event i want to run every 60 seconds but i wonder if this will take up many resources in my database.

```
 CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 60 SECOND
    DO
       UPDATE yourdb.yourtable SET yourcolumn = RAND();
```

If make my event to run every too often,will it impact on the performance of my database?.

Comment: The question in many cases is not if there are drawbacks, but what you are trying to do, and if there is a better way. Doing an update on all records of a table regularly to a random value seems like so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server has very many events happening every minute.  Having an event that happens every 60 seconds is not automatically too frequent

If the event runs quickly and affects a small amount of data, then there should be no particular worry.  The bigger the impact of the event (CPU,I/O,memory,etc) the more cautious you need to be about scheduling.

Comment: Even more - scheduled event is stored as any other stored routine - in the precompiled binary form, so overhead for launching the event is minimal. Sure such event can become a huge problem if its completion needs significant time. It's obvious that if event takes more than 60 sec for completion it will generate an avalanche of scheduled events that consume all the resources.